# Does QGIS Server come with time dimension support (WMS, WCS)?

Tags: wms, qgis-server, time, wcs

I wanted to know if QGIS Server allows publishing data with time dimension support, in the case of services such as WMS or WCS?. If this is possible, how can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked for this feature here : [ticket for dimension feature](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8808) but it hasn't been implemented yet in QGIS 2.14.